Finding text with strikethrough and delete its entire row
I am trying to find any cell on active sheet and delete its entire row. Does anyone have suggestions?
function fontLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];

    for (var i = 0; i < fontLines.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < fontLines[i].length; j++) {
        if (fontLines[i][j] === 'line-through') > -1 {
          sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
          rowsDeleted++;
        }

      }
    }
  }
}


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Copy of Find Font with strike through and delete row. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Use Array.some(), like this:
function deleteRowsWithStrikeThroughInAnyCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let numRowsDeleted = 0;
  ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getFontLines().forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (row.some(format => format === 'line-through')) {
      sheet.deleteRows(rowIndex + 1 - numRowsDeleted);
      numRowsDeleted += 1;
    }
  });
  ss.toast(`Deleted ${numRowsDeleted} rows.`);
}

See Array.some().
